# ActionCable disconnects from redis server after 5 minutes

Tags: ruby, redis, actioncable, rails-api, redis-server

I have a Rails API that has Redis as an adapter of ActionCable.

I only use ActionCable for a simple chat as a part of the whole system.

Everything works perfect, I can subscribe, send messages, receive messages. The problem comes after 5 minutes the server has started, I get an ECONNRESET error in redis gem: Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)

It's been 3 days since i've started trying to solve this issue, i've tried changing redis-server configuration, i've tried changing the way redis initializes on the rails app, i've tried changing the cable.yml configuration, i've tried changing actioncable config and nothing seems to solve this issue, i'm running out of ideas.

I also can't rescue this exception, it just breaks the whole rails app, thats another thing I couldn't solve that's so frustrating.

Btw I am testing in development environment.

This is my cable config:

```yaml
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://192.168.1.6:6379

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://192.168.1.5:6379
  channel_prefix: ChatChannel
  timeout: 30
  max_conns: 8000
  max_persistent_conns: 8000
  
test:
  adapter: async
```

This is my redis initializer:

```rb
require 'redis'

## Added rescue condition if Redis connection is failed
begin
    puts "CREATING NEW INSTANCE OF REDIS"
    $redis = Redis.new(
        :host => "192.168.1.5", 
        :port => 6379, 
        :reconnect_attempts => 10,
        :reconnect_delay => 1.5,
        :reconnect_delay_max => 10.0
    )
    $redis.ping
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
    puts "THERE WAS AN ERROR"
    puts e
end
```

This is the output of the rails app:

```
web_1  | Exiting
web_1  | #<Thread:0x0000559ee244b1d8 /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:151 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:275:in `rescue in io': Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:267:in `io'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:389:in `ensure_connected'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:238:in `block in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `logging'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:237:in `process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:145:in `block in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:300:in `with_socket_timeout'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:84:in `block in listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:81:in `listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:155:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:63:in `block in _read_from_socket': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:52:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:52:in `_read_from_socket'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:45:in `gets'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:378:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:280:in `block in read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in `io'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:389:in `ensure_connected'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:238:in `block in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `logging'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:237:in `process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:145:in `block in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:300:in `with_socket_timeout'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:84:in `block in listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:81:in `listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:155:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:275:in `rescue in io': Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:267:in `io'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:389:in `ensure_connected'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:238:in `block in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `logging'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:237:in `process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:145:in `block in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:300:in `with_socket_timeout'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:84:in `block in listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:81:in `listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:155:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
web_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:63:in `block in _read_from_socket': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:52:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:52:in `_read_from_socket'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:45:in `gets'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:378:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:280:in `block in read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in `io'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `read'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:389:in `ensure_connected'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:238:in `block in process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:325:in `logging'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:237:in `process'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:145:in `block in call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:300:in `with_socket_timeout'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:84:in `block in listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:81:in `listen'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.1/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:155:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
nulimit-web_web_1 exited with code 1
```

This is the output of the redis-server:

```
1:M 08 Dec 2020 20:03:00.438 - Client closed connection
```

Comment: In what environment do you get this error ? Development, testing, or production? Also, looking at your cable config why do you have the same redis URL for dev and prod?

Comment: this problem occurs in development environment, I didn't even tested it on production or testing.

Comment: It seems your redis server is hosted elsewhere. Why no try hosting redis locally and specify `redis://localhost:6379/1` as your redis URL instead.

Comment: I specified my local ip, "192.168.1.5" is the same as localhost

Comment: I am having the same problem in production, could you find a solution ?